# When to generate a new Application Key in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, console, laravel-5.1

Since it automatically sets it for me in my `.env` file when I create the app, I'm not sure when I should run it.

In addition to that, if a second developer comes in, and **clones** the app, does he/she need to run `php artisan key:generate` ?

How do we know exactly when to run `php artisan key:generate` ?

Comment: @tino.codes Incorrect. `APP_KEY` has nothing to do with hashing. Read more: https://tighten.co/blog/app-key-and-you

Comment: @johnRivs you're absolutely right. Four years ago I still believed this myth.

Comment: By default the `APP_KEY` is used within the `PasswordBrokerManager` class that comes with Laravel. If I am not incorrect, this is used for generating hashes for password recovery mails and validating these. If this is correct, all your active password links becomes invalid the second you generate a new application key. Not a big problem, but good to know.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

`php artisan key:generate` is a command that sets the `APP_KEY` value in your `.env` file. By default, this command is run following a `composer create-project laravel/laravel` command. If you use a version control system like `git` to manage your project for development, calling `git push ...` will push a copy of your Laravel project to wherever it is going, but will not include your `.env` file. Therefore, if someone clones your project using `git clone ...` they will have to manually enter `php artisan key:generate` for their app to function correctly.

So, TL:DR the only time you *need* to call `php artisan key:generate` is following a `clone` of a pre-created Laravel project.

Side note: If you try to run a Laravel project with your `APP_KEY` set to `SomeRandomString` (which is the default in your `.env.example` file, you will actually get an error:

> No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. So with that being said, developer A and developer B might have different `APP_KEY` Will that be a problem in the future ?

Comment: I don't believe so, but it is entirely possible. That being said, I haven't seen any cases in my year+ of development with Laravel.

Comment: That's fair enough for me. One last question, is it okay if Developer B leave that `APP_KEY`  blank after cloning the project. Is it a big deal to leave that blank ?

Comment: I just added a "Side Note" for that question. The answer is no, you will not be able to run the project without a key.

Comment: Thank-you. You seemed to answer all the doubt that I have about `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: what if we commit .env file?

Comment: @Maven97 It's not a good idea to commit your `.env` file (unless you're 100% certain that the information contained within it is secure/you don't mind people seeing keys/passwords, etc), but if you do, then you don't need to call this command.

Comment: What is the idea behind that auto-generated key? Whats the whole point?

Comment: @Adam You can see here what the Application Key is used for: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation (scroll down a little). It's used for session data, encryption, etc etc.

Comment: I want to ask about the opposite situation of the first comment: is it ok if developer A and developer B use the same APP_KEY? Would it be problem if I put it in .env.example file?

Comment: @AdemTepe Two developers can use the same APP_KEY, that's fine, and will actually allow sharing data between their two local databases (i.e. if one is corrupted, a restore from the other should work without modification). I'd still advise against putting it in `.env.example` though, simply for security reasons. An external storage, like AWS Secret Manager or similar, is a better solution for shared configuration like keys and whatnot.

Comment: @Adam, the generated APP_KEY can also be add in the app\config\app.php so even it is push it gitlab or github, it will not be needed again to generate as I know all ENV variables should also exist in config folder so there would no need for .env file in the production

Comment: ^ There's a lot wrong about that comment; putting the `APP_KEY` that's defined in `.env`, or any variable that is in `.env` that gets pulled into `config()` directly into their `config/{file}.php` counterpart is a gaping security hole. The point of putting things into `.env` and then pulling them to `config` is to prevent passwords/keys from being directly committed to the repo. Please don't do that unless you aren't concerned with security of those variables.

Comment: yes agree with Tim Lewis, you should never put environment variables in version control.

Comment: Yes agree with Tim lewis

Answer (score 14):

The most important thing to do when cloning a laravel project is to first run `composer update` then `composer install`. The `composer install` command installs any required dependencies for that laravel app.

The steps I took to clone a laravel project required the `php artisan key:generate` command. I can see in my `.env` file that there is an updated `APP_KEY=base64:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` after running this command.

Comment: This worked for me

1) composer update
2) composer install
3) php artisan key:generate

It worked, thanks

Comment: With a full stack Laravel app it's 1) git clone 2) composer update 3) composer install 4) php artisan key:generate 5) php artisan migrate --seed 6) npm install 7) npm run dev

Comment: @Nilpo `composer update` will potentially change the version of Composer itself, which could end up causing issues - so use with caution especially in cases where old code is still in use and the required version of Composer is fixed in the project config...

Answer (score 8):

If you need to generate a key manually, you can do so from any Laravel/artisan-enabled php cli using `php artisan key:generate --show` (supposedly this will not modify any of your existing settings). Then you can use that key string in your config (however you have your secrets saved). I.e. you don't need to run `php artisan key:generate` on the server you are setting up (this can be useful if you're deploying a docker image to a container host like Heroku or AWS App Runner.