# How do I add a new APP_KEY to a Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

I recently was reading this Stack Overflow post

[When to generating a New Application Key in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370134/when-to-generating-a-new-application-key-in-laravel)

where colleagues mentioned that you can run:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

and this will generate a new APP_KEY for your cloned Laravel project. This being a legitimate concern when collaborating and using Github for version control, however, when I tried to run that command I got this error:

```
ldco2016@DCortes-MacBook-Pro-3 ~/Projects/photogallery (master)$ php artisan key:generate                                                                [ruby-2.2.1]
PHP Warning:  require(/Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/artisan:0
PHP   2. require() /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/artisan:16

Warning: require(/Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Call Stack:
    0.0002     240112   1. {main}() /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/artisan:0
    0.0003     242776   2. require('/Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/bootstrap/autoload.php') /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/artisan:16

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/artisan:0
PHP   2. require() /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/artisan:16

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Call Stack:
    0.0002     240112   1. {main}() /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/artisan:0
    0.0003     242776   2. require('/Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/bootstrap/autoload.php') /Users/ldco2016/Projects/photogallery/artisan:16
```

So its not so straightforward and error free. Can anyone lend a hand as to how to generate a new APP_KEY when working on a cloned Laravel project?

Comment: Have you installed composer and run `composer install` yet?

Comment: @aynber, that's right, its looking for the autoload files and that comes with installing composer. Nice! I am ready to mark your response as the correct answer.

Comment: Done. I'm currently doing the same thing on my server, so I recognized the error. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first install composer and run `composer install` so that laravel can access the commands.