# APP_KEY for Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have a Laravel application. I have tested the application on my test server. Now I want to have that on my production servers. My question is do I need to generate APP_KEY for each production server? by doing a `php artisan key:generate` each time I upload to a new server? or can I use the same one I already have in my .env file?

Comment: You don't need to generate for each server

Comment: This will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370134/when-to-generate-a-new-application-key-in-laravel

Comment: Thanks Pankaj & andsadekat. I am not cloning, I FTP files to servers. So should not have error coz of the key. I get an error could be something else. Will check that. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The .env file is not committed when we change our server
you have to copy the example.env file to .env file and then apply the command

> php artisan key:generate

i hope its will work :)