# Is it ok if more than one developer use the same APP_KEY in Laravel for local development?

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, local, laravel-5.8

I am setting up a local development environment for Laravel project and I'm trying to set it up as ready as possible meaning that I want other developers to do minimum effort to start developing locally.

So, in this context, I am thinking that I can put my local APP_KEY in .env.example file so that other developers don't have to run `php artisan key:generate`

Is it a valid thought, would this be a problem, does each developer "have to" generate his/her own key in order to work properly locally?

Note: I have examined the answer here [When to generate a new Application Key in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370134/when-to-generate-a-new-application-key-in-laravel/33370272)

Comment: The `APP_KEY` is used for encryption within Laravel (sessions, csrf tokens, etc.). If you were serving your application on multiple servers you would use the same key, but I don't see a requirement to share keys during development.

Comment: Well, it's not a requirement but I was just trying to understand it better and skip one step for local environment setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is OK.

Since Laravel uses APP_KEY for encrypting cookies (I've just learnt that) including session cookie, it doesn't matter if the developers are using the same APP_KEY in their local environment.

On the other hand, it is important to produce new APP_KEY for the production environment and even change it regularly.

My resource: https://tighten.co/blog/app-key-and-you/